# Error when trying to multiply values from the input sheet I am creating in Excel and VBA

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I am working on an input sheet in excel. I want my output to be the value I typed into the cost cells multiplied by an INDEX MATCH function I created. I Keep experiencing this error in all my attempts to fix it. Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

```
Sub Expense_Save4()

Dim r As Long, i As Long, serv, qu, cost
Dim cost_2 As Variant
    Dim sumValue As Double


' Print Service and Quantity 1-9
        For i = 0 To 8
            serv = Sheet1.Range("U12").Offset(i * 6).Value ' Service i+1
            qu = Sheet1.Range("V14").Offset(i * 6).Value ' Quantity i+1
            cost = Sheet1.Range("V16").Offset(i * 6).Value ' Cost i+1
            cost_2 = cost * (1 + "=WorksheetFunction.INDEX('Products and Services Margins'!$B$2:$AQ$77,WorksheetFunction.MATCH(E" & r + i & ",'Products and Services Margins'!$A$2:$A$77,0), WorksheetFunction.MATCH(C" & r + i & ",'Products and Services Margins'!$A$1:$AQ$1,0))") ' Cost i+1
            If Len(serv) > 0 Or Len(qu) > 0 Then
                .Range("E" & r + i).Value = serv
                .Range("F" & r + i).Value = qu
                .Range("G" & r + i).Value = cost_2
                .Range("H" & r + i).Formula = "=F" & r + i & "*G" & r + i ' Multiply column F and G
                
                End If
```

I tried to redefine my variables and rewrote the formula.

Comment: You can't mix VBA and worksheet formulas together like that. If you're writing a formula, then your string would not include `WorksheetFunction.`. Also the `=` belongs at the beginning of the formula (before `cost`).

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to find a solution if you cut the mammoth in small piece.

Try to validate each part and look the result :

```
row_num = WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
MsgBox row_num 
column_num = WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
MsgBox column_num
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.INDEX(array, row_num, column_num)
```

After that, if you have the right data, you should be able to put those instructions into only one line of code.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't actually mean to include `[]` here.

Comment: Yes @BigBen you are right. [ ] is the Excel syntax to say that this parameter is optional, but for Nicolas Kalman-Serdar he has to put his parameter without [ ]. Thanks, to be more clear, I have removed in my example the Square Brackets for the variable column_num!